# Convert edgelist to path length list

Tags: r, performance, memory, igraph

I am working with a weighted undirected network in R. I have a list of directly connected edges and the weights between them. The weights represents the distance between the vertices. I want to have a list of the path distance between all vertices. My data looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

set.seed(123)

edgelist <- data.frame(
  node1 = sample(1:10, 30, replace = T),
  node2 = sample(1:10, 30, replace = T),
  weight = runif(30, min = 0, max = 5)
)
```

`igraph::distances()` will create a path length matrix.

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edgelist, directed = F)

dm <- distances(g, weight = E(g)$weight)
```

However, this is not desirable in my case, as I have 29000 nodes and a matrix with 800 million cells is too heavy to work with. I can ignore the diagonal because nodes are not self-connected, and since the network is undirected I only need the upper (or lower) triangle of the matrix. Therefore, to decrease computation time, I want a data.frame or similar object type with 3 columns: 'verticeA', 'verticeB', 'path length between verticeA and verticeB'.

How do I achieve this given the initial edgelist? Computational efficiency is key here, since I need to do this with a lot of large edgelists.

Here are some things I tried:

```
pl <- as.table(dm) %>% 
  data.frame() %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%
  filter(Var1 != Var2) %>%
  mutate(
    verticeA = pmin(Var1, Var2),
    verticeB = pmax(Var1, Var2)
  ) %>%
  select(-Var1, -Var2) %>%
  distinct(verticeA, verticeB, .keep_all = T) %>%
  rename(distance = Freq)
```

Computing this makes R freeze, probably because my data is too big.

```
ut <- dm[upper.tri((dm))]
```

Retrieves the upper triangle, which I suppose could be used in combination with `colnames(dm)` and `rownames(dm)`, but I can't quite figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data example in the question, you can generate `distances` grouped by `from` vertex, instead of generating a full distance table, and this should be able to effectively avoid memory overflow.

```
# simplify the graph by keeping the shortest arcs only (if there exist multiple arcs between two adjacent vertices)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edgelist, directed = F) %>%
  simplify(edge.attr.comb = "min")

# grouped by `from` nodes, and compute the distance to the `to` nodes within each group
df <- as.data.frame(
  t(combn(names(V(g)), 2))
) %>%
  setNames(c("from", "to")) %>%
  mutate(dist = t(distances(g, first(from), to)), .by = from)
```

and you will obtain

```
   from to      dist
1     3 10 0.9384556
2     3  2 2.5375587
3     3  6 2.7464233
4     3  5 1.4064305
5     3  4 5.1460144
6     3  9 3.4818967
7     3  8 3.3529676
8     3  7 3.9114715
9     3  1 4.5721909
10   10  2 1.5991031
11   10  6 3.0255022
12   10  5 0.4679749
13   10  4 4.3620589
14   10  9 2.6979412
15   10  8 2.4145120
16   10  7 3.9329983
17   10  1 5.4715983
18    2  6 1.8343116
19    2  5 2.0670780
20    2  4 2.7629559
21    2  9 1.0988382
22    2  8 1.8103096
23    2  7 2.3338952
24    2  1 3.8724953
25    6  5 2.5575273
26    6  4 2.3995912
27    6  9 0.7354735
28    6  8 1.4469449
29    6  7 4.1682068
30    6  1 5.7068069
31    5  4 4.8300339
32    5  9 3.1659162
33    5  8 2.8824869
34    5  7 4.4009732
35    5  1 5.9395733
36    4  9 1.6641177
37    4  8 2.3755892
38    4  7 4.7386347
39    4  1 6.2772348
40    9  8 0.7114715
41    9  7 3.4327334
42    9  1 4.9713334
43    8  7 4.1442048
44    8  1 5.6828049
45    7  1 1.5386001
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answer @ThomasIsCoding. I eventually found a way to upper triangle, which I feel obliged to share here, in case other come to this thread for a solution:

```
dm <- distances(g, weight = E(g)$weight)

UTIndex <- which(upper.tri(dm), arr.ind = T)

df1 <- data.frame(
  verticeA = as.numeric(rownames(dm)[UTIndex[, 1]]),
  verticeB = as.numeric(colnames(dm)[UTIndex[, 2]]),
  path_length = as.numeric(dm[UTIndex])
)
```